# Unable to unload Windows User Profile at logoff

Tags: windows, registry, profile, user-accounts, user-profile

I have an old .net app that runs as a local user account local\User1 for example, on WS2012R2. It runs several Scheduled Tasks as the same user. These tasks run every hour on the hour. After 5 mins (ie. 09:05; 10:05; 11:05 etc) I get 3x errors for each task that completed:

> Windows cannot unload your registry file. The memory used by the
> registry has not been freed. This problem is often caused by services
> running as a user account. Try configuring services to run in either
> the LocalService or NetworkService account. DETAIL - The media is
> write protected.

For design reasons, the application cannot be run a local service account.

What is the impact of not freeing up "memory" in the registry hive? How is memory allocated and monitored to see if poses a problem?

I did test by creating and use a new local\user2 account and assigned it to each task and it resolved the issue, but I still need to understand the impact of not doing this. Any advice would be great.